# Model scheme for moderators of user based topics?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have a topics app that allows users to create topics. For each individual topic, the creator can add moderators to the topic. What's the best way to build this out in the Django model?

Would it be better to just make a separate app that only handles Moderators by checking if a user is a "moderator" for a given topic's ID? Or should I do it from within the Topics app? If so, what would be the best way?

Comment: Why not create custom permissions for the `Topic` model? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#custom-permissions

Comment: This looks like what I need, would you like the post the answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create custom permissions for the Topic model?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#custom-permissions

Answer (score 0):

I think ManyToMany field suits fine )

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    moderators = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```